# How do I get select_tag to display text in front of the parameter?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to display "Year: " inside the 'year' dropbox shown in the image below. How do I append text to the parameter field?

I'm using a select_tag as shown below:

```
<%= form_tag results_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <%= select_tag :season_year, options_for_select(@tournaments.order(season_year: :desc).collect{ |u| [u.season_year] }.uniq, session[:season_year]), class: "btn btn-outline-primary", :onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
   <%= select_tag :tournament, options_for_select(@tournaments_filtered.order(tournament_date: :desc).collect{ |u| [u.lake_name, u.id] }, session[:tournament]), class: "btn btn-outline-primary", :onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
   <%= select_tag :table_select, options_for_select(@result_options, session[:table_select]), class: "btn btn-outline-primary", :onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `include_blank` option to add a *dud* option.

ie add `include_blank: "Year:"`

See [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for more details

Comment: That makes it so "Year:" is a separate option in the drop down, and not to the left of "2022" in this case. I would like it to say Year: 2022, or Year: <selected year>.